# How to avoid toFixed when the value is undefined or delayed response to that value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tofixed

I am seeing this error in my console:

> isNaN(...).toFixed is not a function

Here is some of the HTML code I am writing with Vue.js:

```
<v-flex xs3 class="text-lg-right" 
    v-for="(mrp, index) in [medicine.orderedMedView.combinations[combinationIndex]]" :key="index">
    <div class="primary-header-font">
        &#8377; {{ isNaN((mrp && (mrp.totalPrice - (mrp.totalPrice * (medicine.discountPercentage / 100))))).toFixed(2) ?
        0 :  
        (( mrp && mrp.totalPrice - (mrp.totalPrice * (medicine.discountPercentage / 100)))).toFixed(2) || 0 }} &nbsp;
    </div>
    <span v-if="mrp && mrp.totalPrice != NaN" class="secondary-header-font">
        {{ medicine.discountPercentage }}% 
    </span>
    <span v-if="mrp && mrp.totalPrice != NaN" class="secondary-header-font strike-through">
        &#8377; {{ mrp && mrp.totalPrice && (mrp.totalPrice).toFixed(2) || 0 }} &nbsp;
    </span>
</v-flex>
```

I guess in my medicine state when I use this, the response gets delayed... so maybe that's why it is saying "not a function". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`isNaN` is a function to check wether the value provided is number or not.
It's return value is `true` or `false`.
Therefore, you can't use the function `toFixed` on the return value of isNaN.

Try to rearrange your parentheses so the `toFixed` will be after a number.

Comment: I have rearranged and that fixed my problem and anyways thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

check the variable is `isNaN` before doing toFixed. like the following sample snippet

```js
var a=10.898978
console.log(!isNaN(a)?a.toFixed(2):0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In vue you would prefere to use a method for this sort of statement.

I guess this is one reason why you missed the `toFixed(2)` in the first ternary expression.

So in the method you can imagine something like:

```
price(mrp) {
   let price = mrp && (mrp.totalPrice - (mrp.totalPrice * (this.medicine.discountPercentage / 100));
   return isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
}
```

And in you template:

```
<v-flex xs3 class="text-lg-right" 
    v-for="(mrp, index) in [medicine.orderedMedView.combinations[combinationIndex]]" :key="index">
    <div class="primary-header-font">
        &#8377; {{ price(mrp) }} &nbsp;
    </div>
    <span v-if="mrp && mrp.totalPrice != NaN" class="secondary-header-font">
        {{ medicine.discountPercentage }}% 
    </span>
    <span v-if="mrp && mrp.totalPrice != NaN" class="secondary-header-font strike-through">
        &#8377; {{ mrp && mrp.totalPrice && (mrp.totalPrice).toFixed(2) || 0 }} &nbsp;
    </span>
</v-flex>
```

If you want to avoid some check you can always use the `v-if="medicine"` on the `v-flex` so no value is computed until medicine get populated.